# less: how to scroll horizontally by a screenful

Tags: linux, less-unix

Using the unix command line tool `less`, how do I scroll horizontally? I need to scroll one (or a half) screen to the right or left

Comment: Try `less -S` for horizontal scrolling and scroll horizontally with the arrow keys.

Comment: No need for option -S Horizontal scroll works (using cygwin) even without it

Comment: `-S` causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded. The default is to fold long lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line. Default could be chopped in your system, though.

Comment: For horizontal scrolling , left arrow/right arrow would work (considering I understood your question) or do you wish to enable line wrap?

Comment: No, the default is "Fold long lines" and not chopped - found this default value by using _S on less's "command prompt"

Comment: You can use `less -SEX` (`S` for scrolling horizontaly, `E` to quit on the first EOF & `X` to disable first clear)

Comment: Perhaps ask this question on the Super User Stack Exchange site